# Return my friends and friends of friends using Neo4j's Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes with bi-relations(follow)

I am trying to create a query which I want to return all following nodes of a specific node and the following nodes of his following nodes(3 hopes depth)

For example assume those relations:

-> symbols follow

```
A->B
B->A
B->C
C->B
C->D
D->C
C->E
E->C
```

I am expecting to get this response if I execute the query on node A

B
C
D
E

I tried this:

```
MATCH (user:User {name:'roi'})-[:nearby*1..3]->(foaf)
WHERE NOT((user)-[:nearby]->(foaf))
RETURN user, foaf
```

the problem is that I dont get the node (A) followings only the followings of his followings friends

So I got

C
D
E

I didnt get **B**

anyone could help?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get `B` because your `WHERE` pattern filters out any node that is `[:NEARBY]` to `A`. For that particular relationship it is like saying

```
MATCH A-[:NEARBY]->B
WHERE NOT(A-[:NEARBY]->B)
```

**Edit**

If you want a users' friends and friends of friends to depth three but not the user you can do

```
MATCH (user:User {name:'roi'})-[:NEARBY*1..3]->f
WHERE f <> user
RETURN f
```

Comment: I got error: Query cannot conclude with MATCH (must be RETURN or an update clause) (line 1, column 1 (offset: 0))
"MATCH A-[:NEARBY]->B"
 ^

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I was not giving you a different query to run, I was trying to show you what is wrong with your query. You are explicitly forbidding the thing you want to have returned in your `WHERE` clause, just like I am doing in my answer.

Comment: Ah right gotcha. So how I could get all friends and friends of friends until depth of 3 excluding myself (Without have the starter node in it)

Comment: Remove the `WHERE` clause, or change it to `WHERE user <> foaf`